# How to change Mapmarker icon when no background location service available

Tags: android, kotlin

What to do changes here ------->

init {
locationIndicator.apply {
setMarker3dModel(navigationMapMarker3DModel, locationIndicatorScaler.getCurrentScaleFactor(), LocationIndicator.MarkerType.NAVIGATION)
locationIndicator.locationIndicatorStyle = LocationIndicator.IndicatorStyle.NAVIGATION
}

```
    coroutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        eventBus.events.collect { appEvent ->
            when (appEvent.type) {
                ApplicationEvent.INIT_POSITIONING -> {
                    mapController.mapFragmentWeakRef?.get()?.activity?.let { activityContext ->
                        if (!activityContext.isFinishing) {
                            initPositioning()
                            setupListeners()
                            engMenuLiveData.getPositioningSource().observe(mapController.mapFragmentWeakRef?.get()!!.viewLifecycleOwner) { positioningSource ->
                                when (positioningSource) {
                                    EngMenuLiveData.PositioningSource.CURRENT_LOCATION -> {
                                        enableGNSSWifiCellularPositioning()
                                        initPositioning()
                                    }
                                    EngMenuLiveData.PositioningSource.DEMO_MODE -> enableRoutePlayback()
                                    EngMenuLiveData.PositioningSource.GPX_SIMULATION -> enableGPXPositioning()
                                    EngMenuLiveData.PositioningSource.GNSS_LOCATION -> {
                                        enableGNSSPositioning()
                                        initPositioning()
                                    }
                                    else -> enableDevicePositioning()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                ApplicationEvent.NAVIGATION_START -> {
                    if (appEvent.data != null) startNavigation(appEvent.data as Route)
                }
                ApplicationEvent.ROUTE_RECALCULATION-> {
                    if (appEvent.data != null) startNavigation(appEvent.data as Route, true)
                }
                ApplicationEvent.NAVIGATION_STOP -> {
                    stopNavigation(appEvent.data as NavigationStopType)
                }
                ApplicationEvent.SET_REROUTING_DEBUG -> {
                    if (appEvent.data != null && appEvent.data is Boolean) {
                        locationIndicatorScaler.debugSmallLocationIndicatorEnabled = appEvent.data
                    }
                }
                else -> {
                    /*else*/
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--------------------------->

private val navigationMapMarker3DModel by lazy {
MapMarker3DModel(PositioningConstants.CURSOR_GEOMETRY_FILE, PositioningConstants.CURSOR_TEXTURE_FILE)
}

i am able to listen the background location but once no background location available, then Blue marker icon change to grey. This is the goal.